# how to run this command line sentence using subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

how to run this sentence in subprocess ?

```
./deb -address  12.345.66.3:6000 -file ./234.csv  -key "-key" -secret "password" -id "1234" -insert line


subprocess.call(["","","",""])  but  when "" comes like here in key how to use its `"" -key ""` or `'" -key "'`
```

Need inputs

Comment: `subprocess.call(your_command_as_variable, shell=True)` or use single vs. double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can run your whole command directly in `shell` by quoting with single quote and using `shell=True` argument:

```
subprocess.call('./deb -address  12.345.66.3:6000 -file ./234.csv  -key "-key" -secret "password" -id "1234" -insert line', shell=True)
```

But i would suggest you to leverage **`shlex.split`** to do the splitting and generate the properly escaped command list for you so that you can run it without using shell:

```
import shlex
command = shlex.split('./deb -address  12.345.66.3:6000 -file ./234.csv  -key "-key" -secret "password" -id "1234" -insert line')
subprocess.call(command)
```

FWIW, you should use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.call` (and brothers) on a supported version.